# Ruby on Rails Full Stack application Scaling Up issue on Kubernetes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

We have a RoR based monolith web application which is deployed over Kubernetes. When we try *scale up* the application to more than **1 pod**, The application is not working as expected, the requests to certain pages are taking us to a whole another page, even for authenticated users after some-minutes it takes them back to login page on refresh or while requesting for another pages.[Multi Pods of same full stack web-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ldhk.png)

Comment: How session is managed in your application?

Comment: Rails Gem 'Devise'

Answer (score 0):

Update!
Actual issue is in session storage where session_id stored in rails cache
So, the solution is move the cache storage from *Rails cache* to ***Redis cache***

**Solved:**
add this line in
*/config/environment/production.rb*

```
 config.session_store :cache_store, key: "_app_session"
 config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: "redis://redis:6379/1" }
```